# Qual è il significato di "Tocca, cocchiere"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> "Volevi andare a San Paolo?" fece Agostino appena ebbe chiuso lo sportello e scoprendo i denti cattivi. "Ci verrai con me. Tocca, cocchiere."

Si tratta dello sportello di una carrozza dove Agostino vuole condurre Artemisia per viaggiare fino a San Paolo.

Conosco più o meno i significati di "toccare". Comunque, non riesco a capire il senso di questo verbo nell'espressione "Tocca, cocchiere" che appare nel brano sopra citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probabilmente riferimento a [La presa di San Miniato](https://books.google.it/books?id=bDXioOXWdxkC&pg=PA607&dq=%22disse%20la%20fata:%20ol%C3%A0%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1lZPooMfKAhXD7w4KHXsPCEQQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22disse%20la%20fata%3A%20ol%C3%A0%22&f=false), poema comico di Ippolito Neri.

Non ne vedo altro uso nella lingua italiana, a parte questo. Fatto sta che le rivalità fra i comuni toscani (in questo caso l'opponente è Empoli) riempiono gran parte della letteratura italiana.

Riguardo il significato nel brano su riportato, direi che il cocchiere *tocca* i cavalli del traino per farli partire: un cavallo si dirige toccandolo opportunamente, con le briglie o col fustino, in modo da fargli comprendere le intenzioni del fantino.

Comment: Interessante, ma qual è il significato di questa frase nel poema che hai menzionato?

Comment: Il cavallo si dirige toccandolo opportunamente con le briglie o col frustino. Il tocco del cocchiere può, quindi, significare dare l'abbrivio al cavallo.

Comment: Potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta?

Answer (score 2):

Non sono sicuro visto che non hai postato abbastanza frase, ma se lo sportello si riferisce ad una carrozza, direi che si tratta di un'esortazione a partire:

"Cocchiere, tocca" -> tocca con la frusta i cavalli per farli muovere. Un po' come "Parta, autista"

Comment: In efetti, nei tempi di Artemisia Gentileschi, i viaggi si facevano in carrozza.

Comment: Cerco di aggiungerlo al testo della domanda, magari così è più chiara.